# What are available industry standards for CI/CD of Big Data applications?

Tags: deployment, build, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bigdata

Are there any differences in CI/CD approach when we talk about Big Data applications in Hadoop or Spark and traditional applications?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends how you will update your services. 
If you can use blue/green or rolling deployment strategies you should have no problems updating your servers and will be able to keep your data flowing.